# System not detecting second monitor

Tags: release-juno, display

after finally getting the OS to work after the login screen I'm now having some issues with getting my second monitor to work.

Nvidia drivers are installed (latest ver.)
I ran both `prime-select nvidia/intel` but with no luck.

Any ideas?

*My laptop is an Asus zenbook pro UX580GE, running an Nvidia GTX1050 ti

Comment: How did you install the nvidia driver? I suggest to install the version avaliable on AppCenter if you didn't. And delete any other installed versions, of course.

Comment: If you want to use external display, prime-select should be set to nvidia, Intel is for power saving and external monitors are not supported.